# Send message as user to Facebook Chatbot

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

We develop a chatbot based on the Facebook Messenger Platform.

In the middle of the conversation, we do want to show a complex UI as a WebView. When the user clicks on a button in the WebView, it should close the webview and invoke a user-question in the conversation which will be answered by our bot.

I've managed to show the WebView, send back a message to my backend and give an answer to the user.

But how can I create a new message as "the user" out of my WebView?

**Sample Dialog:**

*Bot (in the conversation):*
Which hat do you want?
[Button to open hat-selection-WebView]

*User (in the WebView):*
[Click on a button in the hat-selection-WebView]

*User (in the conversation):*
I want the green one **< How can I create this message here**

*Bot (in the conversation):* 
Ok, I'll send it to you soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Quick Replies" for this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies

The button text will be the message from the user.

Comment: Nope, I'm in a WebView, I do not have quick-replies in there. But I do want exactly the functionality quick-replies provide... just custom made :)

Comment: ok, i don´t think that´s possible. you can´t just set a custom user message without quick replies, that would be weird and easy to hack.